How to hide overflow between transition of one component to another component in react js
Home.jsx file :
<motion.div id="container" initial={{ opacity:0 }} animate={{ opacity :  1 ,transition:{ delay:0.3 }}} exit={{x:"-100vw",transition:{ ease:"easeInOut", duration:0.3, }}}

About.jsx :
<motion.div id="skills-container"
        initial={{
            opacity:0
        }}
        animate={{
            opacity:1,transition:{
                delay:0.3
            }
        }}
        exit={{x: "-100vw" , transition:{
            ease:"easeInOut"
        }}}
        >

I set overflow hidden to body and it works but my about section scrollbar...i tried set overflow hidden only to that div on home.jsx and overflow auto to section and it doesn't work

To hide overflow during transitions between components in React:

Wrap your components in a parent div.
Dynamically set overflow: hidden during transitions.
Revert to overflow: auto after the transition.

Use onAnimationStart and onAnimationComplete in your motion.div to manage the overflow state.

i tried like onAnimationStart={ ()=> document.body.style.overflow='hidden'  } and OnanimationComplte = style.overflow = 'auto' , but it still shows overflow , can u share an example code
